# How to disable spell check in AntD AutoComplete component in React?

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I couldn't find a way to disable spell check for `AutoComplete` component in Ant Design. Any idea how to achieve this?

```
      <AutoComplete
        options={options}
        onSearch={handleSearch}
        onSelect={handleSelect}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
      <AutoComplete
        options={options}
        onSearch={handleSearch}
        onSelect={handleSelect}
        placeholder={placeholder}
      >
        <Input spellCheck={false} />
      </AutoComplete>
```

This seems to be working but not sure if it might have any side effects.